# How to setup leaflet config in django-leaflet-admin with WMS layer

Tags: python, django, google-chrome, leaflet, wms

i try setting leaflet_config in django like this:

```
LEAFLET_CONFIG = {
'SRID' : 3857,
'DEFAULT_CENTER': (-3.87, 178.59),
'DEFAULT_ZOOM': 14,
'MIN_ZOOM': 3,
'MAX_ZOOM': 20,
'RESET_VIEW': False,
'TILES': [('Aerial Imagery', 'http://otile{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {'type': 'sat', 'ext': 'jpg','attribution': 'Data CC-By-SA by <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap</a>, Tiles Courtesy of <a href="http://www.mapquest.com/">MapQuest</a>','subdomains': ['1','2','3','4']})],
```

}

this is admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Track
from leaflet.admin import LeafletGeoAdmin

admin.site.register(Track, LeafletGeoAdmin)
```

and in django admin map layer not show. i try i use developer tools Network show like this.

```
Request URL:http://otile2.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/14/13453/8352.png
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/fleet/track/1/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36
```

can help solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Old question but I solved this by passing the options when registering the admin.site in `myapp\admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib.gis import admin
from leaflet.admin import LeafletGeoAdmin
from .models import Project, FPV

admin.site.register(
    Project,                      #<-- this is a model
    LeafletGeoAdmin, 
    settings_overrides =  {
        'DEFAULT_CENTER': (59.334591, 18.063240),
        'DEFAULT_ZOOM': 10,
        'TILES': [('','//{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png','')],
    }
)
```